# giving two functionality to a button based on conditions

Tags: android, android-button

i have a button and edit text. i want to work differently on pressing button depending on the condition whether edittext have some text or not?
i tried the code given below but it's not working.

```
String baseurl = null;(global variable)
```

code under button's onclick listener

```
 baseurl = edittext.getText().toString();
    if(!baseurl.isEmpty()){
        body...
    }else if(baseurl.trim().length() == 0 || baseurl.isEmpty() || baseurl == null){
        Intent i = new Intent(URLFetcher.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

if condition is working but else if is not working app is crashing on 2nd condition.

Comment: post the stacktrace..

Comment: it means your base url is null and your checking the lenght of it

Comment: instead of checking it to null or length or isEmpty you can simply do `TextUtils.isEmpty(baseUrl)` and also paste your stackTrace

Comment: You can also change your else if to else if(baseurl == null  || baseurl.isEmpty() || baseurl.trim().length() == 0){
        Intent i = new Intent(URLFetcher.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

Comment: replace `baseurl.isEmpty()` with `!TextUtils.isEmpty()`. should work fine

Comment: Have the null check first to ensure its not null before performing any operation on it so that it doesn't crash

Comment: have you declared `MainActivity` in `AndroidManifest.xml`??
Crash log will give better idea about the crash

Comment: Please mark one of the answer that helped you

Answer (score 2):

Just use **TextUtil** library

```
 String baseurl = edittext.getText().toString();
 if(TextUtils.isEmpty(baseurl) 
 {
     Intent i = new Intent(URLFetcher.this, MainActivity.class);
     startActivity(i);
 }
 else
 {
 // body
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use

```
else if(baseurl.trim().length() == 0 || baseurl.isEmpty() || baseurl == 
null)
```

just use `else`

and then add your intent code in else part

```
else{

Intent i = new Intent(URLFetcher.this, MainActivity.class);

startActivity(i);

}
```

Comment: at very first i tried this but it didn't work for me that's why i tried above method. thanks anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
 baseurl = edittext.getText().toString();
   if(baseurl == null || baseurl.isEmpty() ){
        Intent i = new Intent(URLFetcher.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
else
{
 body...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code for button click listener

```
baseurl = edittext.getText().toString();

if(!baseurl.isEmpty()){
    //Code for edittext has a url
}else{
   // Code for edittext has nothing
     Intent i = new Intent(URLFetcher.this, MainActivity.class);
     startActivity(i);
}
```

You don't need to check again in else clause. If `!baseurl.isEmpty()` is false that means `baseurl` has a 0 length. `baseurl` will never be `null` as per your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `equalsIgnoreCase()` method of string:

```
baseurl = edittext.getText().toString();
    if(!baseurl.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
        body...
    }else if(baseurl.trim().length() == 0 || baseurl.isEmpty() || baseurl == null){
        Intent i = new Intent(URLFetcher.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

initialize your baseUrl to an empty string instead of null

```
String baseurl = ""; (global variable)
```

and then check the conditions

```
if(!baseurl.isEmpty()){
        body...
  }else if(baseurl.trim().length() == 0 || baseurl.isEmpty() || baseurl == null){
        Intent i = new Intent(URLFetcher.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```